# iPhone UITableViewCell SwipeGesture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I wanted to simply animate custom view in a custom table cell by swiping left or right in that cell. I am loading the cell from the xib.

This is the code I used to populate the cell from the xib.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

CustomCell *CustomCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (CustomCell == nil)
{
    NSArray *cells =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for (UIView *view in cells)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            CustomCell = (CustomCell *)view;
            break;
        }
    }

}
CustomCell.textLabel.Text = @"this is a text";
return CustomCell;
}
```

What I need is to swipe a cell to reveal a background view with buttons. I have searched and find many tutorials regarding this but none of the same is using the custom cell with xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this project

[UITableViewCell Swipe](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/SideSwipeTableView)

Answer (score 1):

hi try this for your requirement of swipe a cell to reveal a background view with buttons.

[jzswipecell](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jzswipecell)